# Junit test a class with a bunch of @Pointcut

Tags: spring, junit, aop, aspect, pointcut

Is there an elegant way to unit test the following class?

```
public class PointCuts {
    @Pointcut(value = "execution(* com.eg.app..*.*(..))")
    public void all() {
    }
    @Pointcut(value = "execution(* com.eg.app.service.advice..*.*(..))")
    public void log() {
    }
    @Pointcut(value = "execution(* com.eg.app.service.auth..*.*(..))")
    public void auth() {
    }
    @Pointcut(value = "execution(* com.eg.app.setup.auth..*.*(..))")
    public void authtest() {
    }
    @Pointcut(value = "all() && !log() && !auth() && !authtest()")
    public void app() {
    }
    @Pointcut(value = "execution(* com.eg.app.repo.CustomerRepo.save(..))")
    public void saveCustomer() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no point in testing this list of pointcuts because without advices (before, after or around) they don't do anything. So what you want to test are the advices using these pointcuts.